# What colors could a pool of nanorobots be?

Tags: nanotechnology

The classic color for a mass of nanorobots is gray (or "grey" for British nanobots).  As far as I can tell, this color has been enshrined in the public consciousness by the [Gray Goo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_goo) disaster scenario.

But why gray?  More generally, what colors could a pool (say 1 deciliter) of nanorobots be and what would affect the color?

I assume there are a whole number of factors that would affect the color, including the elemental composition (pure gold is a different color from pure silver), the types of structures involved (graphite is a different color from carbon), or possibly even the size. I'm not looking for a formula like "f(elements, structure, size) -> color" but more for just some general guidance on what colors are known to be possible for things the size of nanorobots and if particular colors would require something weird to achieve.

Comment: The color depends heavily on what the nanobots are made of

Comment: Why is anything colored the way it is? Pigments (or lack of), and structural coloration are two major factors. See [Color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color) In particular color of objects. Please do some more research.

Comment: As written this is very open ended since you're asking about what possible colors something, ill defined, **could** be. You should refine this question to not ask about grey goo in other worlds, or for a list of possible colors, but ask for help determining the color your bots will be in your world, or alternatively ask whether it makes sense that your bots in your world are a specific color.

Comment: What colour(s) do you want it (them) to be? If they're built for surveillance or tactical infiltration, then they might mimic the background. Please give us more to go on than an open ended question without context.

Comment: VTC despite a selected (and quite good, mind you) best answer. The question, itself, is fundamentally opinion-based. What's the best color is no better than the many closed "what's the best name" or "what's the best weapon for war" questions. To be honest, if you can't explain why you can't live with picking a color, or can't explain why the rules of your world are getting in the way of establishing a color, then you're question isn't ready for prime time.

Comment: @JBH The question is not about what color is best, it's about what types of things affect the color of a nanorobot.  There are multiple answers (the accepted answer included) that have mechanisms for how the makeup of the nanorobots affects their color.

Comment: @Zags I appreciate your observation, but let me quote from your own question. "What colors could a pool of nanorobots be?" and "what colors could a pool (say 1 deciliter) of nanorobots be?" In fact (A) You're allowed to ask one and only one question. You're asking at least two. (B) Nowhere in your question do you ask what materials a fictional creation could be made out of to affect color. Asking that will get this closed as opinion-based anyway because no one knows what material limitations fictional nanites will have (despite the answers).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**It depends on how big they are.**

Different sized nanoparticles have different color scatter / absorption properties.

[image: nanocolor]

[Nanosilver rainbow: a rapid and facile method to tune different colours of nanosilver through the controlled synthesis of stable spherical silver nanoparticles†](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2016/ra/c6ra08336f/unauth)

> A rapid and simple one-pot reaction to synthesize stable, spherically
> shaped silver nanoparticles (AgNps) of different sizes producing
> distinct optical properties in aqueous solution at ambient temperature
> has been developed. Each system contains various sizes of silver
> nanoparticles showing rainbow colours with the peak wavelength of the
> absorption spectra ranging from 400 to 750 nm. Seven different colours
> of nano silver were developed through the controlled synthesis of
> spherical silver nanoparticles using silver nitrate as the metal
> precursor...

So with your bots.  An interesting prospect - if the bots could change their size they could change their color.  All of the solutions above are nanoparticles of the same composition, differing only in size.  Pretty sweet!

Answer (score 4):

It depends....

If they are relatively transparent (perhaps made out of oxide electronics, or diamond) they will almost certainly look white due to scattering. But it depends some on how they agglomerate and also how the agglomerations trap light. Even if they are relatively non-absorptive if the light is trapped it will be absorbed after multiple bounces then it could still look black.

If they organize into thin films then inference effects might make it look think a thin film of oil giving it a shimmering effect.

If they are absorbing (perhaps graphitic carbon - Buckey balls or nanotubes) they perhaps black - but is that good or bad? good for absorbing light to get energy, but maybe bad for heating up...

If they they have thin metallic coatings they plasomonic resonances may give them strong colors that depends on their size. A famous example is colloidal gold in glass giving medieval stain glass its deep red color. The color can depend some on the surrounding medium, but basically the light causing electrons in the metal to move around is a type of absorption that can be strong absorbing for example the blue/green portion of the spectrum to give gold its color.

So if you have a bunch in a container - do they want to close pack in a tight arrangement or do they organize into some structure. Form birefringence can lead to interesting types of interference like the shimmer of butterfly wings or opalescence and photonic crystals that can have strong colors.

In general it can be hard for small particles not to stick to each other, but if nanobots are possible it seems if dumped into a bottle or a pool that they might want to organize for a variety of reasons.... which might make them colorful.

Answer (score 2):

## Gray

You can be pretty sure it's going to be something grayscale or otherwise neutral. You might end up with lighter or darker grays depending on what particular metals or other materials the nanobots' casings are made out of. If they have a particular need to stay cool in sunlight, maybe they're white or light gray. If they would benefit from absorbing light, such as solar-powered bots, maybe they're black. Regardless, unless the nanobots are specifically designed to be appealing to the human eye, they have no practical need to reflect certain wavelengths in the 400-700 nm range, so they will not have any particular color.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with vantablack, for similar reasons, and also why not to collect energy once it presents itselfs.

Generally a lump of nanomachines, is not like a regular lump of material, or colloidal liquids, or a bunch of loose grains of different sizes(which loose their color smaller the particles are, and becoming grayish, as an example different silicone carbide powders used as abrasive and which particle color is black)

Main difference is that nanomachines lump is not a chaotic thing, but some configuration which is result of a programming for the most types of nanomachines which people envision. It has to be, for to then be able to act as that nanobot thing

In that sense, forming the outer layer is a fraction of the "programming" (maybe the smartest one, but as data) of the piece of nanobots material.
And what is its default color depends on the programming of its surface area/layer, and it can be any, really, similar to how butterflies have their colors on the wings of them. (If you happens not to know, then this random link from google for a start https://asknature.org/strategy/wing-scales-cause-light-to-diffract-and-interfere/ )

The guys want energy, or needs energy, and extracting it from light may be an option, and being black is understandable.

If it isn't something rogue, then marking it with a specific pattern or characteristic shine and color to distinguish it from regular materials, as an object, for ease of humans - it also makes sense, and I guess the thing can do no worse than those butterlies in this aspect.

So, you are not bound here by any limitation in general. So nothing wrong to be of any color and texture variety.

Some less sofisticated ones, when we do not care about their colors, or are not cable to care, what's theirs one - depends on specifics of how it made, what it is. Not possible to say, gray is probable, black is possible, but other colors also possible, it more solid thing, so nothing wrong with black.